# Filter pandas pivot_table result like a regular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to filter the Pandas data frame, like in the example below it works fine:

```
print data[data['ProductCategory'].isin(['ProductA'])]
```

But when I try to do the same on the resulting pivot table:

```
pivot = pandas.pivot_table(
      data,index=['ProductCategory', 'Currency', 'Producer'], 
      values=['Price','Quantity','FxRate'],
      aggfunc={'Price': np.sum, 'Quantity': np.sum,'FxRate': np.mean})

print pivot[pivot['ProductCategory'].isin(['ProductA'])]
```

I get a key error:

> File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3838)
>     File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3718)
>     File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12294)
>     File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12245)
>   KeyError: 'ProductCategory'

A describe() of the pivot table gives this :

```
        FxRate           Price        Quantity
count   48.00           48.00           48.00
mean     0.93    4,717,051.34   46,446,338.82
std      0.20   20,603,134.35  188,008,495.83
min      0.64  -16,088,043.02 -137,804,378.35
25%      0.73      -87,306.39           83.75
50%      1.00       41,198.26      682,025.97
75%      1.00    2,999,491.53    7,489,198.82
max      1.25  137,804,362.15  939,610,000.00
```

A pivot.info() gives the following output:

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 48 entries, (ProductA, ProductB, ProductC) to (ProducerA, ProducerB, ProducerC)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
FxRate         48 non-null float64
Price          48 non-null float64
Quantity       48 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)

memory usage: 2.3+ KB
None
```

And a pivot.head() gives this:

```
                                          FxRate      Price   Quantity  
ProductCategory Currency      Producer                                 
ProductA        EUR           ProducterA   1.00       0.90       1.10   
                              ProducterB   1.00       0.90       1.10   
                GBP           ProducterB   1.25       1.12       1.37   
ProductB        EUR           ProducterA   1.00       0.90       1.10   
                GBP           ProducterC   1.25       1.12       1.37
```

Comment: The error looks like 'ProductCategory' is not a column, it looks like you set it as the index, can you show what your pivot table looks like

Comment: I added the output of pivot.describe() to the question

Comment: That tells me nothing, show what `pivot.info()` shows, also perhaps `pivot.head()`

Comment: I added head() and info() output

Comment: Well it should be clear why you get the error, 'ProductCategory' is not a column, it's part of your multi-index so you want to select all 'ProductCategory' rows that are 'ProductA'? `pivot.loc['ProductA']` should work

Comment: Yes, I want to extract only the lines relative to 'ProductA'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89602/discussion-between-aminek-and-edchum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProductCategory`, `Currency`, and `Producer` are now part of the index after the `groupby` operation.  Try to reset the index of your DataFrame named  `pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)` and then use `loc` to make selections as usual.

```
>>> pivot[pivot['ProductCategory'].isin(['ProductA'])]
  ProductCategory Currency    Producer  FxRate  Price  Quantity
0        ProductA      EUR  ProducterA    1.00   0.90      1.10
1        ProductA      EUR  ProducterB    1.00   0.90      1.10
2        ProductA      GBP  ProducterB    1.25   1.12      1.37
```

You can then reset the index on the result if desired.

Alternatively, you can just use `loc` as follows on the original `pivot`:

```
>>> pivot.loc['ProductA']
                     FxRate  Price  Quantity
Currency Producer                           
EUR      ProducterA    1.00   0.90      1.10
         ProducterB    1.00   0.90      1.10
GBP      ProducterB    1.25   1.12      1.37
```